# Chrome - automatically resume download - disable this feature

Tags: google-chrome

while downloading avi I'm watching it at the same time. But when download is finished, chrome tries to rename it from .avi.crdownload to .avi. It fails because this file is being used by movie player.
And here comes the issue, chrome automatically restart the download and delete what was already downloaded. Is there a way to disable download auto restart?

Thanks
kurin